# Start setInterval again after clearInterval

Tags: jquery

I have one animation here: http://jsfiddle.net/r55w2u23/

When i click on the yellow container, the animation will stop. But when i click on the square to start moving again, it wont work. I can't find what's wrong in my code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var refreshIntervalId = setInterval(update, 1000);

    $('.square').click(function() {
        if (refreshIntervalId != undefined) {
            refreshIntervalId = setInterval(update, 1000);
        }
    });
$('#container').click(function() {
        if (refreshIntervalId != undefined) {
            clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
        }
    });

});

function update() {
    $('#container').animate({ left:"+=20px"});
}
```

Comment: add `e.stopPropagation();` as the first instruction inside your `.square` click handler. This will prevent the outer `#container` click event to trigger and reset your interval. the click event bubbles up from `.square` to `#container` handler, causing it to stop

Comment: I haven't think about that. Thanks for pinpointing the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few problems

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var refreshIntervalId = setInterval(update, 1000);

    $('.square').click(function (e) {
        //need to stop the propagation else the container click also will get triggered
        e.stopPropagation();
        //if undefined need to start the interval
        if (refreshIntervalId == undefined) {
            refreshIntervalId = setInterval(update, 1000);
        }
    });
    $('#container').click(function (e) {
        //if the timer is not defined there is no need to clear it
        if (refreshIntervalId != undefined) {
            clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
            //just calling clear interval will not clear the value of the timer reference
            refreshIntervalId = undefined;
        }
    });

});

function update() {
    $('#container').animate({
        left: "+=20px"
    });
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8o8hLh51/)

Answer (score 1):

first of all you need to stop the event propapagation or your click on square also registers on the container and it stops again.

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

(as Arun Johny, already stated)
but also stop using setIterval, insted do a recursion to make sure the aniamtion has ended
http://jsfiddle.net/r55w2u23/2/